# Do Carmo Problem - Section 3.3 - 12

Tags: differential-geometry

The problem statement is as follows -

Consider the parametrised surface $$ x(u,v) = \bigg(\sin u\cos v , \sin u\sin v , \cos u + \log(\tan\frac{u}{2}) 
+\phi(v)  \bigg) $$

where  $\ \phi\ $ is a differentiable function. Prove that

a. The curves $\ v \ $ = const. are contained in planes which pass through the z axis and intersect the surface under a constant angle $\ \theta\ $ given by

$$ \cos \theta = \frac{\phi'}{\sqrt{1+(\phi')^2}}  $$

My attempt :

For given parametrized surface $$ x(u,v) = \bigg(\sin u\cos v , \sin u\sin v , \cos u + \log(\tan\frac{u}{2}) 
+\phi(v)  \bigg) $$ with $ \ \phi \ $  - differentiable function we can write

$ x_u = \bigg( \cos u\cos v \ ,\cos u \sin v \ , \cot u \cos u \bigg)$ 
$ x_v = \bigg( -\sin u\sin v \ ,\sin u \cos v \ , \phi' \bigg)$

$x_u\wedge x_v  = \begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k\\ 
\cos u \cos v & \cos u \sin v  & \cot u \cos u \\ 
-\sin u \sin v & \sin u \cos v & \phi' 
\end{vmatrix} \\ = i\bigg( \phi' \cos u \sin v - \cos ^2 u \cos v \bigg) - j\bigg( \phi' \cos u \cos v + \cos ^2 u \sin v \bigg) + k\bigg( \sin u \cos u  \bigg) $
The unit normal  N = $\frac{x_u\wedge x_v}{||x_u\wedge x_v||}$ .

We first calculate $||x_u\wedge x_v||$

$$||x_u\wedge x_v|| \ = \ \sqrt{(\phi')^2\cos ^2u \sin ^2 v + \cos ^4u \cos ^2v - 2\phi'\cos ^3u \sin v \cos v + (\phi')^2\cos ^2u \cos ^2v \\ + \cos ^4u \sin ^2v  + 2\phi'\cos ^3u \cos v\sin v   + \sin ^2u \cos ^2u }$$
$||x_u\wedge x_v|| = \cos u \sqrt{1 + (\phi')^2}$

Hence, the unit normal to surface $ x(u,v) $ is given by

$$N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + (\phi')^2}} \bigg( \phi' \sin v - \cos u \cos v , \  - \phi' \cos v - \cos u \sin v , \  \sin u   \bigg)$$

Now, the unit normal vector to the plane passing through the curve $ v $ = const. and the z-axis , say V, will be given by

$ V = (-\sin u, \cos u , 0 ) $ and then $ \theta $ will be

$ \cos\theta = N\cdot V$

$$ \cos \theta  = \frac{\phi' (-\sin ^2 v ) + \cos u \cos v \sin v - \phi' \cos ^2 v - \cos u \sin v \cos v }{\sqrt{1+ (\phi')^2}}$$

$$ \cos \theta  = \frac{ - \phi' } {\sqrt{1+ (\phi')^2}}$$

Why am I getting the undesired -ve sign here? Is it due to the wrong direction of vector V or something else went wrong?

Comment: The ambiguity between $\theta$ and $\pi-\theta$ is always there.

Comment: Thank you prof. @Ted Shifrin for your clarification.